# android kotlin CoroutineScope run another once one is fully finished

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a fragment that has two Coroutine launch functions
one fetches data from network/DB

the other is to check if room is empty and to dipslay a popup to the user.

functions

```
//this function gets the data
private fun initUI() = launch {

    val data = viewModel.data.await()
    data.observe(this@fragment, Observer {
        if (it == null){
            Log.d(TAG, "initui observer is null")
            return@Observer
        }
            adapter = StoreAdapter(it, activity.baseContext)
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
            activity.progressDisplay()
    })
    checkData().join()
}

//this function is designed to go after initUI()
private fun checkData() = launch {
    delay(3000L) //temp solution
    val check = viewModel.check.await()
    Log.d(TAG, "$check")
    if(check == 0L){
        activity.showPopup(getString(R.string.error_text), getString(R.string.data_error), retry = true)
    }
}
```

if I do just checkData().join() it gives me my popup if no data is in the DB to begin with then works fine after it. so I have added a 3 second delay however I don't like this way but am not sure if there is another way?

*@edit*

the view models just does a Lazy Deffered which calls my repository

repo init

```
init {
    source.downloadedData.observeForever { data->
        saveData(data)
    }
}
```

**viewmodel.data repo code**

```
override suspend fun getData(): LiveData<List<item>> {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        initJsonData()
        return@withContext myDao.getAll()
    }
}
```

initJsonData is a check date function that if true returns data from the network.

once we create init the repo we observe the data from the network forever and save it to the room dB as needed.

**view model check code**
follows the same logic as getting the data to some extent, but I simply do a select count from the room table and return the results.

```
  override suspend fun checkData(): Long {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        Log.i(TAG, "checkData")
        isDataEmpty()
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to me `viewModel.check` depends on the result of `viewModel.data`, is it true? can you provide the code for them?

Comment: @Dusk I have added more of the code

Answer (score 1):

You have an `Observer` which is forever observing the downloaded data and when
it observes the data, it proceeds to save it inside your DB. But remember this doesn't guarantee that the code inside this observer (i.e. `saveData(data)`) is going to be called immediately after the code that fetches the data, So let's break it down like this:

1. When you call `initUI()` method, the first line of code fetches the data and waits for the data to be only fetched and **it's not waiting for it to be saved**.
2. After that, your `checkData()` and `saveData(data)` will race to perform their logic at the same time. And sadly before `saveData()` saves anything inside the DB, `checkData()` returns the error to you.

One solution is to `saveData()` after you fetched it and before calling `checkData().join()` in the same coroutine like this:

```
private fun initUI() = launch {
    val data = viewModel.data.await()

    //Some other codes...

    saveData(data.value) //If it's an asynchronous function, await for it.


    checkData().join()    
}
```

Please notice that if `saveData(data)` is asynchronous, you must `await` for it.